# What does 央企 mean?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I understand it is sort of a State-owned business, but it should be 国企 in Chinese, 央 does not make sense here, it seems. And in dictionaries and practical usage, the Chinese character 央 is not a word used singlehandedly, so it is hard to understand the real meaning of the phrase.

Answer (score 6):

央 means 中央; 央企 is the shortened form of 中央企业.

In short, 国有企业 are owned by the country; among them, those owned by 中央 (central government), more specially, by 国务院国资委 (the State-owned Assets Supervision and Administration Commission of the State Council) are called 中央企业, those owned by 地方政府 (local government) are called 地方企业.

You can get a list of 央企 from [央企名录](http://www.sasac.gov.cn/n2588035/n2641579/n2641645/index.html).

Reference: [什么是央企？和国企有什么区别？哪个的待遇更好？](http://www.sohu.com/a/125669513_499647)

Answer (score 0):

According to [this link](https://zhidao.baidu.com/question/1923753689671999187.html)

> 央企： 属于中央部委
>
> 国企： 国家作为投资主题成立的企业